# ¿Cómo crear una Vista Materializada en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a crear una **Vista Materializada** en SQL, osea, quiero hacer una vista que tenga una clave foránea (FK).

Lo que necesito hacer es:

Crear una **Vista Meterializada** en la base **"MiBase1"**
haciendo un **SELECT** de una tabla de otra base de datos **"MiBase2"**

Se puede hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Puedes proveer mas detalles específicos para aclarar tu pregunta, tal vez incluyendo un ejemplo concreto de lo que quieres?

Comment: Te comento un poco lo que quiero hacer, estoy haciendo una aplicación en C# que utiliza muchas bases de datos y utilizo Entity Framework para el manejo de base de datos y quiero crear una Relación de FK de una tabla de la BASE1 a otra tabla de la BASE2 y quiero evitar tener que hacer dos instancias de entity y tener que recorrer cada instancia, por eso se me ocurrió crear una vista en la BASE1 que haga un SELECT de la BASE2 y quiero que esa VISTA sea con "foreign key" y se que existe un tipo de vista que lo hace, se llama Vista Materializada. Espero que se entienda, gracias!

Comment: No, no es muy claro. Creo que entiendo la idea general, pero no entiendo lo que quieres decir con *quiero que esa VISTA sea con "foreign key"*. Y por lo que veo que estas tratando de hacer y la motivacion tras ello, sospecho que usar una vista materializada tal vez no sea la solucion adecuada. Te recomiendo de modificar tu pregunta para exponer con todo lujo de detalles tus modelos entity framework, y explicar por medio de ejemplos concretos y detallados lo que pretendes lograr. Con eso, la comunidad podrá proponerte la mejor manera de manejar tu situacion.

Comment: Si entiendes inglés, te puede ser útil repasar este hilo: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Lo que pides no es posible. Uno de los requisitos para crear una vista materializada, en SQL Server, es que las tablas a las que hace referencia estén en la misma base de datos. Si amplias la pregunta para incluir esa información, con gusto escribo una respuesta que indique que no se puede.

Comment: Entiendo, solo para aclarar, se puede hacer una vista que consuma datos  de otra base de datos, pero, siendo Materializada no. Entendí bien?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En SQL Server, el término oficial para una vista materializada es *vista indexada*.

Tu pregunta:

> Crear una Vista Meterializada en la base `MiBase1` haciendo un `SELECT` de una tabla de **otra base de datos** `MiBase2`

No, no es posible. Hay muchos requisitos que se deben respetar para poder crear una vista indexada. Y el que tu vista haga referencia a tablas en diferentes bases de datos viola uno de los requisitos. Nota lo que dice la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms191432.aspx) al respecto:

> La vista solo debe hacer referencia a tablas base que estén en la misma base de datos que la vista.